# Change background color of imshow subplots in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am plotting images in a loop in the following way:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 35))
for i in range(len(batchX)): # 32 images
   plt.subplot(8, 4, 1 + i)
   plt.title("IMG{} - Pred: {},  GT: {}".format(i+1, classes[int(pred[i][0])], classes[int(batchy[i])]))
   plt.imshow(batchX[i])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I'd like to change the background color of each plot depending on a certain condition (as you might have guessed, when the prediction equals the ground truth or not).

I tried adding this in the loop right before the `imshow()`:

```
if classes[int(pred[i][0])] == classes[int(batchy[i])]:
   plt.gcf().set_facecolor("green")
else:
   plt.gcf().set_facecolor("red")
```

However, only the last `plt.gcf()` call will be taken into account since it's when `plt.show()` runs that it will look at the color setting, making all the backgrounds either green or red.

In what other way could I achieve this?

Comment: I am trying to get a single image containing all the plots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [subplots()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplots) and iterate over the Axes, to finally show all the plots with their correct background colors.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8,4, figsize=(20, 35))
# Flattens the Axes grid to more easily iterate
axs = axs.flatten()
# You must make sure that len(axes) >= len(batchX) (and batchy)
for i, X in enumerate(batchX):
    ax = axs[i]
    ax.set_title("IMG{} - Pred: {},  GT: {}".format(i+1, classes[int(pred[i][0])],\
        classes[int(batchy[i])]))
    if classes[int(pred[i][0])] == classes[int(batchy[i])]:
        ax.set_facecolor("green")
    else:
        ax.set_facecolor("red")
    ax.imshow(X)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The background stays white. Neat trick to flatten the axes grid.

Comment: Before trying to change the background color, do you have any transparency in your images ?

Comment: No transparency. I might not have been clear enough, I'm talking about the background of the plots, outside of the images, not the images' backgrounds.

Comment: In other words, the area changed when using `facecolor=(x, y, z)` in the creation of the subplots. But using this in `plt.subplots()` will change the whole plot's background color. I'm guessing the whole plot is considered to have a unique background, meaning that the subplots don't have a background region assigned, but only one large common background.

Comment: Does it mean you want to change the figure's facecolor ? That would mean you want as many figures as plots.

Comment: Yes basically. I guess I shouldn't use subplots then.

Comment: Indeed, you can't change the figure's color and show it unless you do some kind of animation (or several displays). You could draw a plot A within a plot B, where A's ax has a facecolor, or you could add padding to you plots around the images. The figure will remain white (or uniform) but you would have colored borders.

Comment: Thanks for the help. To pad the images I used `img_bordered = cv2.copyMakeBorder(X, border, border, border, border, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[0, 255, 0])`.

Comment: Great idea. I hope the rendering satisfies your needs.